# Insert multiple rows into Access database by looping through values and skipping blanks

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to loop through a series of comboboxes on my form, skip the blanks and then added them to a database, but it seems to be failing - any idea how I can do this?

```
For i = 1 To 8
    If Not (("cboOption" & i).Value = "") Then
        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO db (mID, uID) VALUES (("cboOption" & i).Value = "", StudentID.Value);"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not 100% sure, but the code you have might throw a method or data not recogonised error. Anyway, the following code should sort it.

```
For i = 1 To 8
    If Len(Me.Controls("cboOption" & i).Value & vbNullString) <> 0 Then
        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO db (mID, uID) VALUES (" & _
                  Me.Controls("cboOption" & i).Value & ", " & _
                  StudentID.Value & ");"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
Next
```

Just make sure to wrap the values inside single quotes if they are string values.

```
        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO db (mID, uID) VALUES ('" & _
                  Me.Controls("cboOption" & i).Value & "', " & _
                  StudentID.Value & ");"
```